# back of card needs to fill the entire screen

Tags: css, fullscreen, back, flip

I found a 3d card flip on jsfiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/GDdtS/3610/) and i edited it to this:
http://jsfiddle.net/qCPrj/

I am trying to make the back side of the "card" fill the entire screen of the webpage. Someone suggested to add the code:

```
positition: absolute;
left: 0;
right: 0;
```

to the back class, but this won't change the width of the back side. My question would be, how do I get the back side of the "card" to fill the entire screen?

edit*

The front size needs to stay 400px wide and 200 px high, but i want the backside to be fullscreen, so when you mouse-over the backside appears and expands to cover the entire screen.

Answer (score 0):

you have to set height 100% to all the parent elements to fill the space accordingly - so in your case add

```
html, body, .flip, .card, .front, .back{height:100%}
```

[Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mAgh5/)

Comment: Sorry, I guess I was not clear enough in the post, I edited that now, but what I wanted was that the front side of the card is 400px by 200 and when you mouse-over, the back side appears and expands to cover the entire screen, again my apologies for not being clear enough.

Comment: just add `width:400px; height:200px` to `.flip .card .front` and `width:100%; height:100%;` to `.flip .card .back`

Comment: That would not give the desired result, because when your mouse is not on the front side, the "card" will still flip over.
http://jsfiddle.net/mAgh5/3/

Comment: im not sure what you mean

Comment: check my jsfiddle in the last comment, if your mouse is not on the black front card, the card will still flip over.

Answer (score 0):

the width and height of your class is only 400X200 so technically at the max ...it will fill that part. you need to increase the size of the ".flip"

Comment: doing that, increasing the .flip size to be bigger, and keeping my front card to 400x200, it would mean that even if my mouse is not on my front card, but is in the bounds of the .flip class, the card would still flip